# Generate new function from old function with only one argument set

Tags: python, function, lambda, arguments

Suppose I have a function

```
def oldfunction(arg1,arg2,arg3):
    print(arg1,arg2,arg3)
```

I want to create a new function in which I have set the first argument to 10.  The new function behaviour would be:

```
>>> new_function(20,"30")
10 20 '30'
```

One way to do this would be to use a lambda function:

```
>>> newfunction = lambda arg2,arg3: function(10,arg2,arg3)
>>> newfunction("ten",[10])
(10, 'ten', [10])
```

But, suppose I didn't know in advance how many arguments "oldfunction" takes.  I still want to create a new function that is the same as "oldfunction", but with the first argument set, and all subsequent arguments left open.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following example allows you to bind a 10 to the first argument position in oldfunction and then supply the remaining two arguments in *args. So, try this:

```
def newfunction(*args):
    return oldfunction(10, *args)
```

Answer (score 8):

Try [functools.partial](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial

new_function = partial( oldfunction, 10 )
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be a functional solution, and your code would look something like this for your exact case:

```
from functools import partial

def newfunction(*args):
    return oldfunction(10, *args)

newfunction(20, 30)
(10, 20, 30)
```

10 is bound as the first argument to oldfunction, followed by *args.